# Listing Directory Entries with Qt on Remote Windows Server

Tags: qt, remote-access, qdir

I am on a Windows Server which is in the same network as the Server with the computer name `service`.
I got this simple code which tries to list the content

```
QFileInfoList fiList = QDir("\\service\\Documents").entryInfoList(QDir::Files);
qDebug() << "sizeof filist: " << fiList.size();
for (const QFileInfo& fi : fiList)
{
   qDebug() << fi.absoluteFilePath();
}
```

The output is the following:

```
sizeof filist:  0
```

I make sure that the folder is shared on the network by checking the properties and also using the windows explorer. I can access the folder via Windows Explorer.

Is the functionality I am trying to achieve not possible with QDir?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there are 2 backslashes more needed because \ needs to be escaped.

So the right code would be:

```
QFileInfoList fiList = QDir("\\\\service\\Documents").entryInfoList(QDir::Files);
qDebug() << "sizeof filist: " << fiList.size();
for (const QFileInfo& fi : fiList)
{
   qDebug() << fi.absoluteFilePath();
}
```